# Pentaho CDE Table Component

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, kettle

I got the following columns out of a query:

Year, Type, Value

I want a table showing how much value each year and type has. But the **table Component** in CDE puts Year and Type at the left, and then all values at the right.

How can I put Types at the top? So I get Years on the left column, Types on the top line, and the table showing the Values, like a crosstable. I don't see such configuration options in the table Component.

Comment: Or maybe there is a better component than "table Component" that I haven't seen?

Answer (score 1):

The table component gets you the data as it comes. Your data is not in crosstab form, so the table won't do it automatically.

You can either change your query to return 1 column per type (especially easy if you use MDX) or change your data structure in the postFetch of the component.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 
But the "Type" options are not fixed, so I can't do a query as that. Can I use MDX to access my SQL Server directly? Could you dplease show me an example of how the MDX query would be? Left column should show years, top column Type, and each cell the value. Just something to get me started, as I have no knowledge of MDX.

Comment: You need to have a Mondrian cube built, of course. And you need to know MDX to write the query. Bear in mind that the structure of the table is not dynamic by default, you'll need to manipulate some of the object's properties on the post-fetch, setting column types, headers, widths, etc.